# How do I know my CPU-cooler / heatsink will fit?

Tags: cpu, cooling, cpu-cooler

This might seem a trivial question, but it's not trivial or intuitive to me.

I bought a new motherboard ASUS 68HM PLUS:
[image]

Here's another picture of just the [ounting bracket (is that what it's called?) The screws form a rectangle with the approximate dimensions of 5cm x 9.5cm.
[image]

The CPU is an AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7. The socket type is FM2+.
From what I've gleaned online, as long as you know the socket type of your CPU (and your motherboard supports that socket type obviously), then you should be able to purchase and install any CPU heatsink/cooler that supports that socket.

Obviously, that's wrong. I took the heatsink out of an HP motherboard (incidentally the same place where I got my CPU). Only upon assembly of the ASUS motherboard did I realize that the screws of the heatsink to the mounting bracket did not line up (they didn't form a rectangle, they were more or less equidistant from the center of the fan, forming a square).

How is it that two motherboards, that support and perfectly socket an FM2+ CPU, can have two completely different mounting brackets for the heatsink? This tells me that there must be more to purchasing a heatsink than just knowing the CPU's socket type - but I have no idea what that would be. How can I know for certain that any new heatsink I buy will fit on my ASUS motherboard? Additionally, if you have any specific product suggestions, I'm all ears - especially if they are cheap stock units.

Comment: Since HP made the motherboard, they must have made a custom heatsink and mounting too. They don't have to be compatible with any off-the-shelf standards.

Comment: That makes sense. Does that mean my original assumption is actually correct - I can buy a heatsink advertised as FM2+ and it should work with this specific ASUS motherboard?

Comment: Checked what the width, height, and length of the heatsink are, then measure if, given the orientation of the board, it can be installed.  The heatsink from the HP machine will not fit on the motherboard you describe.  HP heatsinks only support the motherboard that it came with.